# gettext compile fails in crosstool-ng build on cygwin

Tags: linux, cygwin, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng

I am new to crosscompiling and I followed the steps from [using-crosstool-ng-and-cygwin by MAKSYM SHYTE](http://www.geekdroppings.com/2014/04/11/using-crosstool-ng-and-cygwin/)

The crosstool fails to build gettext when generating crosscompiler for i686-nptl-linux-gnu target

```
build  = x86_64-unknown-cygwin
host   = x86_64-unknown-cygwin
target = i686-nptl-linux-gnu or x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

NOTE: This gnulib [patch from Ken Brown](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2016-03/msg00088.html) is needed to get gettext module compile. Alternatively, it also compiles if we just comment out  #include  in /usr/include/sys/types.h [as per thorrr from bountysource](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/36191964-crosstool-build-fails-on-cygwin-2-5-2)

[UPDATE1] building gettext module for host gives the exact same errors for the x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu target also.

The ct-ng build fails in the linking phase while building gettext module for host.

```
[ALL  ]    libtool: link: x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin-g++ -shared -nostdlib 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/crtbeginS.o  
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-message.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-po-error.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-po-xerror.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-read-catalog-abstract.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-po-lex.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-po-gram-gen.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-po-charset.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-read-po.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-read-properties.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-read-stringtable.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-open-catalog.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-dir-list.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-str-list.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-read-catalog.o 
../woe32dll/.libs/libgettextsrc_la-c++color.o ../woe32dll/.libs/libgettextsrc_la-c++write-catalog.o 
../woe32dll/.libs/libgettextsrc_la-c++write-properties.o 
../woe32dll/.libs/libgettextsrc_la-c++write-stringtable.o 
../woe32dll/.libs/libgettextsrc_la-c++write-po.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-msgl-ascii.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-msgl-iconv.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-msgl-equal.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-msgl-cat.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-msgl-header.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-msgl-english.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-msgl-check.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-file-list.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-msgl-charset.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-po-time.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-plural-exp.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-plural-eval.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-plural-table.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-sentence.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-libexpat-compat.o ../woe32dll/.libs/libgettextsrc_la-c++format.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-c.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-sh.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-python.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-python-brace.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-lisp.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-elisp.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-librep.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-scheme.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-java.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-csharp.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-awk.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-pascal.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-ycp.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-tcl.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-perl.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-perl-brace.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-php.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-gcc-internal.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-gfc-internal.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-qt.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-qt-plural.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-kde.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-kde-kuit.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-boost.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-lua.o .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-javascript.o 
.libs/libgettextsrc_la-read-desktop.o ../woe32dll/.libs/libgettextsrc_la-gettextsrc-exports.o  
 -L/home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/intl/.libs 
../gnulib-lib/.libs/libgettextlib.dll.a 
-L/home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/buildtools/lib /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/intl/.libs/libintl.dll.a 
-lncurses ../intl/.libs/libintl.dll.a /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/buildtools/lib/libiconv.dll.a 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/../lib 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib -L/lib/../lib 
-L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib 
-L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../.. -lstdc++ -lgcc_s -lgcc 
-lcygwin -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgcc_s -lgcc 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/crtend.o  -g -O2 
-Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--disable-auto-import   -o .libs/cyggettextsrc-0-19-6.dll 
-Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libgettextsrc.dll.a

[ALL  ]    .libs/libgettextsrc_la-libexpat-compat.o: In function `is_XML_LARGE_SIZE_ABI':
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/libexpat-compat.c:74: undefined reference to `XML_GetFeatureList'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/libexpat-compat.c:74:(.text+0x28): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_GetFeatureList'
[ALL  ]    .libs/libgettextsrc_la-libexpat-compat.o: In function `rpl_XML_GetCurrentLineNumber':
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/libexpat-compat.c:90: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/libexpat-compat.c:90:(.text+0x96): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
[ALL  ]    .libs/libgettextsrc_la-libexpat-compat.o: In function `rpl_XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber':
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/libexpat-compat.c:99: undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/libexpat-compat.c:99:(.text+0xb6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber'
[ALL  ]    .libs/libgettextsrc_la-format-kde-kuit.o: In function `format_parse':
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:236: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:236:(.text+0x27d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_ParserCreate'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:244: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:244:(.text+0x29f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_SetElementHandler'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:248: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:248:(.text+0x2b8): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_Parse'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:258: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:258:(.text+0x2d3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_Parse'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:269: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:269:(.text+0x2eb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_ParserFree'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:261: undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:261:(.text+0x4ec): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_GetErrorCode'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:261: undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:261:(.text+0x4f3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `XML_ErrorString'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:264: undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
[ALL  ]    /home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src/format-kde-kuit.c:264:(.text+0x52a): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output


[ERROR]    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[ERROR]    make[6]: *** [Makefile:2388: libgettextsrc.la] Error 1
[ALL  ]    make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src'
[ERROR]    make[5]: *** [Makefile:2300: all] Error 2
[ALL  ]    make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools/src'
[ERROR]    make[4]: *** [Makefile:1742: all-recursive] Error 1
[ALL  ]    make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools'
[ERROR]    make[3]: *** [Makefile:1608: all] Error 2
[ALL  ]    make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin/gettext-tools'
[ERROR]    make[2]: *** [Makefile:380: all-recursive] Error 1
[ALL  ]    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin'
[ERROR]    make[1]: *** [Makefile:336: all] Error 2
[ALL  ]    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/l64/.build/i686-nptl-linux-gnu/build/build-gettext-host-x86_64-build_unknown-cygwin'
[ERROR]
[ERROR]  >>

[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Installing gettext for host'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@257]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_gettext_backend[scripts/build/companion_libs/330-gettext.sh@131]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_gettext_for_host[scripts/build/companion_libs/330-gettext.sh@63]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_companion_libs_for_host[scripts/build/companion_libs.sh@36]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@646]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
```

[UPDATE2] filled in all the logs before "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

1) The build logs show that the "building and installing gettext module for build" succeeding but it failing when "building and installing gettext module for **host**" - What could be the difference since build and host architecture is the same - x86/cygwin ?? Am I missing any configuration settings?

2) If anyone got the crosstool-ng working on recent cygwin releases for a linux 64/32bit targets, please share detailed steps or links.

[UPDATE3]

As I was going no where trying to crosscompile for linux(ubuntu) I tried **arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi and armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf targets, cygwin can generate the cross-compoilers just fine for both targets**. Its strange that crosscompiler generation for 32 and 64 bit plain linux target fails in Cygwin. I am probably missing something trivial.

[/UPDATE3]

Anyone with recent success on (x86/i686)_linux target please share your steps or links.

Comment: any log before `[ERROR]    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` ?

Comment: @matzeri : No errors before that. I have updated the post to include all the logs after the linker command.

Comment: `undefined reference to 'XML_GetFeatureList'` is the error. You need to link your lib against a library that provide that simbol. It can be an external lib.

Comment: @matzeri thanks. I will search for it and update here.

Comment: @matzeri I can see all thrse symbols defined in libexpat-compat.c/libexpat-compat.h which is already part of the gettext source [ .build/src/gettext-0.19.6/gettext-tools/src ]. I can see in the logs it gets compiled into  libgettextsrc_la-libexpat-compat.o . The above linker log also shows the .o being pulled in. Not sure what can cause them to be undefined.

Comment: all these are referenced inside a DYNLOAD_LIBEXPAT or HAVE_LIBEXPAT blocks. hardcoding #define DYNLOAD_LIBEXPAT 1 at appropriate locations did not work - I got a linker crash at an earlier stage on 2 separate builds targets - i686-nptl-linux-gnu and x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The undefined symbols (XML_GetFeatureList XML_GetCurrentLineNumber XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber XML_ParserCreate XML_SetElementHandler XML_Parse XML_ParserFree XML_GetErrorCode XML_ErrorString) were defined in expat-2.1.0.tar - a separate package. I could not get that to link into the crosstool builds but I got past the gettext linker error by **removing** the following from the .config file

```
CT_EXPAT=y 
CT_EXPAT_NEEDED=y 
CT_EXPAT_VERSION="2.1.0"
CT_EXPAT_V_2_1_0=y
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but using a different configuration:

```
build  = x86_64-unknown-cygwin
host   = x86_64-w64-mingw32
target = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

> I could not get that to link into the crosstool builds but I got past the gettext linker error by removing the following from the .config file

I got gettext to link too by removing the expat lines from the .config. But 
only to end up with a configure error for "native gdb" later on.

```
[EXTRA]    Building native gdb
[ERROR]    configure: error: expat is missing or unusable
```