# qt 5.7.0 make error in cygwin after configure

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, cygwin, cross-compiling

[UPDATE2] qt 5.7 seems to have issues cross compiling under the windows environment (cygwin/mingw). qt 5.5 can be cross compiled relatively easily.

I am cross compiling qt 5.7.0 to armv7 linux target on raspberry pi using a toolchain I generated with crosstool-ng on cygwin.

Host: cygwin
Toolchain: armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf (generated via crosstool-ng)
Target : armv7 linux

I downloaded and extracted qt 5.7.0 tarball and extracted it under the cygwin directory structure from within the cygwin shell (i.e I didnt use winzip/7zip to extract the files).

configure command:

```
~/qtpi]$ ./configure -prefix /cygdrive/c/qt5pi -debug-and-release -no-accessibility -device
linux-rpi3-g++ -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -platform cygwin-g++ 
-device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/admin/x-tools/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/bin/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf-
-sysroot /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/admin/x-tools/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -v
```

configure completes as follows...

```
   ...
   ...
   xkbcommon-x11........... no
   xkbcommon-evdev......... no
   zlib ................... yes (bundled copy)


NOTE: Qt is using double for qreal on this system. This is binary
incompatible against Qt 5.1. Configure with '-qreal float' to create a build 
that is binary compatible with 5.1.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'. Once everything is 
built, you must run 'make install'. Qt will be installed into 
/cygdrive/c/qt5pi

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from the 
previous build.
```

At this point running make give the following error:

```
~/qtpi]$ make
cd qtbase/ && ( test -e Makefile || /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qmake /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qtbase.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && /usr/bin/make -f Makefile
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/admin/qtpi/qtbase'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make[1]: *** [Makefile:43: sub-src-make_first] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/admin/qtpi/qtbase'
make: *** [Makefile:78: module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

I am stuck here for half a day. AFAIK this does not seem to be related to dos-unix line endings or mingw shell ( I get the same error via mingw too)

[UPDATE1] here is the first 200+ lines of /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/Makefile for reference.

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: qtbase
# Generated by qmake (3.0) (Qt 5.7.0)
# Project:  qtbase.pro
# Template: subdirs
# Command: /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qmake -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qtbase.pro
#############################################################################

MAKEFILE      = Makefile

first: make_first
QMAKE         = /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qmake
DEL_FILE      = del
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= if not exist
MKDIR         = mkdir
COPY          = copy /y
COPY_FILE     = copy /y
COPY_DIR      = xcopy /s /q /y /i
INSTALL_FILE  = copy /y
INSTALL_PROGRAM = copy /y
INSTALL_DIR   = xcopy /s /q /y /i
DEL_FILE      = del
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = move
SUBTARGETS    =  \
        sub-src \
        sub-examples \
        sub-tests \
        sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro


sub-src-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @if not exist src/ mkdir src/ & if not exist src/ exit 1
    cd src/ && $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/src.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd src/ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qmake_all
sub-src: FORCE
    @if not exist src/ mkdir src/ & if not exist src/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd src/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/src.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile
sub-src-make_first: FORCE
    @if not exist src/ mkdir src/ & if not exist src/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd src/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/src.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile 
sub-src-all: FORCE
    @if not exist src/ mkdir src/ & if not exist src/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd src/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/src.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile all
sub-src-clean: FORCE
    @if not exist src/ mkdir src/ & if not exist src/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd src/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/src.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile clean
sub-src-distclean: FORCE
    @if not exist src/ mkdir src/ & if not exist src/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd src/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/src.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile distclean
sub-src-install_subtargets: FORCE
    @if not exist src/ mkdir src/ & if not exist src/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd src/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/src.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install
sub-src-uninstall_subtargets: FORCE
    @if not exist src/ mkdir src/ & if not exist src/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd src/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/src.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall
sub-examples-qmake_all: sub-src-qmake_all FORCE
    @if not exist examples/ mkdir examples/ & if not exist examples/ exit 1
    cd examples/ && $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/examples/examples.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd examples/ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qmake_all
sub-examples: sub-src FORCE
    @if not exist examples/ mkdir examples/ & if not exist examples/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd examples/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/examples/examples.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile
sub-examples-make_first: sub-src-make_first FORCE
    @if not exist examples/ mkdir examples/ & if not exist examples/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd examples/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/examples/examples.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile 
sub-examples-all: sub-src-all FORCE
    @if not exist examples/ mkdir examples/ & if not exist examples/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd examples/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/examples/examples.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile all
sub-examples-clean: sub-src-clean FORCE
    @if not exist examples/ mkdir examples/ & if not exist examples/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd examples/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/examples/examples.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile clean
sub-examples-distclean: sub-src-distclean FORCE
    @if not exist examples/ mkdir examples/ & if not exist examples/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd examples/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/examples/examples.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile distclean
sub-examples-install_subtargets: sub-src-install_subtargets FORCE
    @if not exist examples/ mkdir examples/ & if not exist examples/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd examples/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/examples/examples.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install
sub-examples-uninstall_subtargets: sub-src-uninstall_subtargets FORCE
    @if not exist examples/ mkdir examples/ & if not exist examples/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd examples/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/examples/examples.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall
sub-tests-qmake_all: sub-src-qmake_all FORCE
    @if not exist tests/ mkdir tests/ & if not exist tests/ exit 1
    cd tests/ && $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/tests/tests.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd tests/ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile qmake_all
sub-tests: sub-src FORCE
    @if not exist tests/ mkdir tests/ & if not exist tests/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd tests/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/tests/tests.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile
sub-tests-make_first: sub-src-make_first FORCE
    @if not exist tests/ mkdir tests/ & if not exist tests/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd tests/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/tests/tests.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile 
sub-tests-all: sub-src-all FORCE
    @if not exist tests/ mkdir tests/ & if not exist tests/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd tests/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/tests/tests.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile all
sub-tests-clean: sub-src-clean FORCE
    @if not exist tests/ mkdir tests/ & if not exist tests/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd tests/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/tests/tests.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile clean
sub-tests-distclean: sub-src-distclean FORCE
    @if not exist tests/ mkdir tests/ & if not exist tests/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd tests/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/tests/tests.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile distclean
sub-tests-install_subtargets: sub-src-install_subtargets FORCE
    @if not exist tests/ mkdir tests/ & if not exist tests/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd tests/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/tests/tests.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile install
sub-tests-uninstall_subtargets: sub-src-uninstall_subtargets FORCE
    @if not exist tests/ mkdir tests/ & if not exist tests/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd tests/ && ( if not exist Makefile $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/tests/tests.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile uninstall
sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro-qmake_all:  FORCE
    @if not exist qmake/ mkdir qmake/ & if not exist qmake/ exit 1
    cd qmake/ && $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qmake/qmake-aux.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile.qmake-aux
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd qmake/ && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qmake-aux qmake_all
sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro: FORCE
    @if not exist qmake/ mkdir qmake/ & if not exist qmake/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd qmake/ && ( if not exist Makefile.qmake-aux $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qmake/qmake-aux.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile.qmake-aux ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qmake-aux
sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro-make_first: FORCE
    @if not exist qmake/ mkdir qmake/ & if not exist qmake/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd qmake/ && ( if not exist Makefile.qmake-aux $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qmake/qmake-aux.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile.qmake-aux ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qmake-aux 
sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro-all: FORCE
    @if not exist qmake/ mkdir qmake/ & if not exist qmake/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd qmake/ && ( if not exist Makefile.qmake-aux $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qmake/qmake-aux.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile.qmake-aux ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qmake-aux all
sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro-clean: FORCE
    @if not exist qmake/ mkdir qmake/ & if not exist qmake/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd qmake/ && ( if not exist Makefile.qmake-aux $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qmake/qmake-aux.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile.qmake-aux ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qmake-aux clean
sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro-distclean: FORCE
    @if not exist qmake/ mkdir qmake/ & if not exist qmake/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd qmake/ && ( if not exist Makefile.qmake-aux $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qmake/qmake-aux.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile.qmake-aux ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qmake-aux distclean
sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro-install_subtargets: FORCE
    @if not exist qmake/ mkdir qmake/ & if not exist qmake/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd qmake/ && ( if not exist Makefile.qmake-aux $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qmake/qmake-aux.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile.qmake-aux ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qmake-aux install
sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro-uninstall_subtargets: FORCE
    @if not exist qmake/ mkdir qmake/ & if not exist qmake/ exit 1
    @set MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd qmake/ && ( if not exist Makefile.qmake-aux $(QMAKE) /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/qmake/qmake-aux.pro -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile.qmake-aux ) && $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qmake-aux uninstall


Makefile: qtbase.pro .qmake.conf .qmake.cache mkspecs/win32-msvc2012/qmake.conf mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        mkspecs/common/angle.conf \
        mkspecs/common/msvc-base.conf \
        mkspecs/common/msvc-desktop.conf \
        mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        mkspecs/features/win32/qt_config.prf \
        mkspecs/win32-msvc2012/qmake.conf \
        mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
        mkspecs/qmodule.pri \
        mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf \
        .qmake.conf \
        .qmake.stash \
        mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf \
        mkspecs/features/qt_parts.prf \
        mkspecs/modules/qt_tool_syncqt.pri \
        mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
        mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds_post.prf \
        mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        mkspecs/features/exceptions_off.prf \
        mkspecs/features/qt_example_installs.prf \
        mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf \
        mkspecs/features/precompile_header.prf \
        mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        mkspecs/features/file_copies.prf \
        mkspecs/features/qt_build_extra.prf \
        mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf \
        mkspecs/features/win32/rtti_off.prf \
        mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
        mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        qtbase.pro
    $(QMAKE) -qtconf /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/bin/qt.conf -o Makefile qtbase.pro
mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:
mkspecs/common/angle.conf:
mkspecs/common/msvc-base.conf:
mkspecs/common/msvc-desktop.conf:
mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
mkspecs/features/win32/qt_config.prf:
mkspecs/win32-msvc2012/qmake.conf:
mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf:
mkspecs/qmodule.pri:
mkspecs/features/qt_build_config.prf:
.qmake.conf:
.qmake.stash:
mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
mkspecs/features/win32/default_pre.prf:
mkspecs/features/qt_parts.prf:
mkspecs/modules/qt_tool_syncqt.pri:
mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:
mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds_post.prf:
mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
mkspecs/features/exceptions_off.prf:
mkspecs/features/qt_example_installs.prf:
mkspecs/features/qt_docs_targets.prf:
mkspecs/features/precompile_header.prf:
mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
mkspecs/features/file_copies.prf:
mkspecs/features/qt_build_extra.prf:
mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf:
mkspecs/features/win32/rtti_off.prf:
mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:
mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
qtbase.pro:
qmake: FORCE
```

Please help me get past this!

Comment: Check out the last paragraph under this [step 3](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/install-win.html#step-3-set-the-environment-variables), it may be related.

Comment: As a side note, have you considered running Linux in a VM, and doing your builds there? As a bonus, builds should be faster than with Cygwin/MinGW (due to the way they need to emulate Unix-like environment on Windows), and you'll sidestep a multitude of headaches caused by slight differences here and there.

Comment: @hyde thanks I will look into the path and env variables some more and update here. Linux VM is not an option yet for our project. I am hoping its a one time effort to get qt to cross compile under cygwin.

Comment: I cleaned up the PATH and other potential QT related env items that could interfere. Still the same error on make.

Comment: I seem to remember having renamed *sh* binary to disable it, to get things to work (maybe 5 years ago, don't remember details, sorry).

Comment: though I didnt understand how disabling sh will help, I was desperate so I tried! Did not help though - [make: /bin/sh: Command not found].

I am looking to see if VS2012 ARM Cross Tool can help.

Its an existing MSVC project with qt and opencv that I am trying to cross compile for raspberry pi. opencv went through fine, qt to go.

Comment: `syntax error: unexpected end of file` could be due to CRLF newline.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: @matzeri thanks, I did run dos2unix on the make files to sanitize them even though I unzipped and un-tarred the tar.gz file completely under cygwin ( I conciously dit not use use winzip/7zip to extract the files - as mentioned in the post).

Can this still create CRLF issues?

Comment: Looks on the `/home/admin/qtpi/qtbase` for some hint. May be there is an incomplete makefile or and inport from a different file type or a script

Comment: Can you show us `/home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/Makefile` or is it too large? If it is, can you locate the default goal (the first one) and show us its recipe?

Comment: @renaud: I will post the makefile shortly. I didnt understand your "locate default goal" please clarify.

[at]matzeri: are you suggesting there may be a problem with the downloaded source?

Comment: @sith: a `Makefile` declares targets (`<target>: <pre-requisites>`). The first encountered in the `Makefile` is the default goal.

Comment: @renaud, thanks.  I have pasted the first 200 or so lines from the makefile in the post above. I guess "first: make_first" is the default goal. Please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [cannot-compile-qmake-for-win32-g-cross-compiling](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/) pointed out by @Torugobeck, I tried cross compiling Qt5.5 and it seems to have gone through the motions and completed 'make' and 'make install' under Cygwin - but with a cygwin-g++ platform ( instead of win32-g++ platform option under mingw )

Configure succeeded in 2 stages as outlined in the [above link](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/).

Start with this configure command :

```
./configure -prefix /cygdrive/c/qtpi5 -debug-and-release -no-accessibility  
-opensource -confirm-license -make libs -platform cygwin-g++ 
-device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -sysroot /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/admin/x-tools/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -v
```

This succeeded in generating the qmake binary for windows.

Then edit the /qtbase/configure file as outlined in the [above link](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/).

Continue with this configure command :

```
 ./configure -prefix /cygdrive/c/qtpi5 -debug-and-release -no-accessibility  
-opensource -confirm-license -make libs -platform cygwin-g++ 
-device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -sysroot /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/admin/x-tools/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot 
-v -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/admin/x-tools/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/bin/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf-
```

There was a windows version detection related failure in function /home/admin/qtpi/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qglobal.cpp:determineWinOsVersionPost8

I forced the function to return true and fillout relevant OS version information on the out param.

After this configure completed. 'make' took just 4 hrs and completed without errors - as did 'make install' next.

I compiled a minimal GUI program qith qt5 and was able to execute it on the target - raspberry PI/arm7-linux.

In short, **cygwin was able to cross compile qt 5.5 successfully** using a [linux-armv7 cross compiler generated using crosstool-ng - also under cygwin- see UPDATE3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740555/crosstool-ng-build-fails-on-cygwin-for-a-i686-nptl-linux-gnu-architecture).

p.s the GUI executable fails to launch the GUI and seems to just hang there with the following warning...

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
```

I am investigating this.

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.qt.io/topic/69482/cannot-compile-qmake-for-win32-g-cross-compiling

in this link from qt support forum, looks like qt 5.7 has some issues for compiling it on windows.
I'm using version 5.5 that has no problems

Comment: thanks for the link, that post also hints fundamental issues with qt 5.7 on windows. I will try 5.5 tomorrow and update here.

Comment: I tried compiling qt5.5 under mingw and its failing earlier at the configure stage with - " tchar.h: No such file or directory"

I used the following command : 
./configure -prefix /c/qt5pi -debug-and-release -no-accessibility  -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -device li
nux-rasp-pi2-g++ -platform  win32-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/c/cygwin64/home/admin/x-tools/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnue
abihf/bin/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /c/cygwin64/home/admin/x-tools/armv7-rpi2-linux-gnueabihf/armv7-rpi2-lin
ux-gnueabihf/sysroot -v

Can you please share your detailed steps?

Comment: actualy I followed a tutorial to build qt for beaglebone, there is a very similar one for raspi http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/

Comment: well I already had the cross compiler built via crosstool-ng. hence I didnt need the visualgdb to mount and sync from a live target. Also the build succeeded on -platform cygwin-g++. splitting the configure into two seemed to be the key. see my answer below.